# Random characters appearing in string?

Tags: c, char

I am trying to normalize a C string that contains a number so that additional zeros are added in the beginning make the whole string contain MAXCOL characters (which is 8 ..)

Everything seems to be working fine up to the point where i add the original string back into the normalized string : Some random characters are being added idk how, it's like i am adding characters that are after the `\0` character, making the string look weird when shown on screen.

I hope someone has a clue as to what i am doing wrong.

To give you an idea, `t_operande2D` is a 2D array of char[MAXCOL]

```
void normaliser_operandes(t_operande2D mes_operandes){
    // This procedure adds zeros to the beginning of each mes_operandes to have a normalized nbr of MAXCOL chars
    // 
    // Lets say it receives mes_operandes[0] as 10, it will convert it to 00000010

    int j, nombre_caracteres; // Nbr of original caracters
    t_operande2D operandes_normalises; // The normalized output (temp variable)

    for(int i=0; i<MAXLIGNE; i++){
        // Count the original nbr of chars
        nombre_caracteres = 0;
        for(int j=0; (j<MAXCOL && mes_operandes[i][j]!='\0'); j++){
            nombre_caracteres++;
        }
        // Add needed 0s to the beginning
        for(j=0; j< MAXCOL - nombre_caracteres; j++){
            operandes_normalises[i][j] = '0';
        }
        operandes_normalises[i][j] = '\0';

    strncat(operandes_normalises[i], mes_operandes[i], nombre_caracteres);

    strncpy(mes_operandes[i], operandes_normalises[i], MAXCOL);
    }
}
```

EDIT: after the edit, the strncat is giving me the "stack around operandes_normalises was corrupted..." error :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`strcat` expects both of it's arguments to be NUL terminated. By the looks of things, `operandes_normalises[i]` begins with `MAXCOL - nombre_caracteres` amount of `'0'` `char`s, but isn't followed up by a NUL terminator (`'\0'`) to indicate the end of the string.

`strcat` will look for the end of the string before appending `mes_operandes[i]` to `operandes_normalises[i]`. If the junk characters are between the `'0'`'s and `mes_operandes[i]`, then that's your problem - `operandes_normalises[i]` is missing a terminator.

If the junk characters are after `mes_operandes[i]`, then `mes_operandes[i]` is the one that isn't NUL terminated.

Print out `operandes_normalises[i]` after adding the `'0'`'s to the start of the string to see if this is the case. By the looks of things I'm guessing there's a good chance it is.

ie. If `MAXCOL - nombre_caracteres` is 5, `operandes_normalises[i]` could be:

```
"00000random_garble\0" /* just so happens to be a '\0' somewhere in memory */
```

Therefore `mes_operandes[i]` will be added after the junk characters.

**EDIT:** Thought I might add, `strcat` is unsafe, especially in the way it's being used here - no checking to ensure that `mes_operandes[i]` will fit in `operandes_normalises[i]`.

Consider using `strncat`, however note that it writes **n + 1** characters to the destination. From the manpages:

> If src contains n or more characters, strncat() writes  n+1  characters to  dest  (n  from src plus the terminating null byte).  Therefore, the size of dest must be at least strlen(dest)+n+1.

Comment: yup you are right! they do appear after adding the 0s
now, i tried adding '\0' after adding them but that gives me a runtime exec error :( so i am guessing i should do this in another way ?

Comment: @DanyKhalife: Did you try `operandes_normalises[i][j] = '\0';` before `strcat`? Also `strcat` can be unsafe and there's a chance it'll cause a buffer overflow in your code - that can cause a crash. Consider using `strncat`.

Comment: yup, thats what i did (please check the edit) and i changed strcat to strncat, tho now im getting a new error (overflow) which i don't understand: i specified the exact nbr of characters it needs to add, and its like it is always adding 1 more character, because if i put -1 after nombre_caractere, it will work just fine (no error) but will be one char short ..

Comment: @DanyKhalife: `strncat` writes 1 more character for the NUL terminator. If you don't want to be 1 character short, remove one of the `'0'`'s being added, ie `MAXCOL - nombre_caracteres - 1` in your `for` loop.

Comment: ok now i get it, thanks a lot @AusCBloke, very very helpful !